# Priority queue is not definede VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, priority-queue

I use VS 2012 and it gives the error in this IDE, weorks fine with 2017 and 2019
It returns

`1>consoleapplication2.cpp(41): error C2039: 'priority_queue' : is not a member of 'std'`

and

`error C2065: 'priority_queue' : undeclared identifier`

What could be the reason for this ? Can I use some `#ifdef` to get rid of this? I need to get this to work on visual studio 2012 that is why I am trying. I use C++, i also use the realted libraries. I only commented out to make sure what would be the difference.

```
// program in c++ to use priority_queue with class 
#include <queue>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std; 
  
#define ROW 5 
#define COL 2 
  
class Person { 
  
public: 
    int age; 
  
    float height; 
  
    // this is used to initialize the variables of the class 
    Person(int age, float height) 
        : age(age), height(height)
    { 
    } 
}; 
  
// we are doing operator overloading through this 
/*bool operator<(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
{ 
  
    // this will return true when second person  
    // has greater height. Suppose we have p1.height=5  
    // and p2.height=5.5 then the object which 
    // have max height will be at the top(or  
    // max priority) 
    return p1.height < p2.height; 
} */
  
int main() 
{ 
  
    std::priority_queue<Person>; 
  
    float arr[ROW][COL] = { { 30, 5.5 }, { 25, 5 }, { 20, 6 }, { 33, 6.1 }, { 23, 5.6 } }; 
  
  /*  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) { 
  
        Q.push(Person(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])); 
  
        // insert an object in priority_queue by using 
        // the Person class constructor 
    } 
  
    while (!Q.empty()) { 
  
        Person p = Q.top(); 
  
        Q.pop(); 
  
        cout << p.age << " " << p.height << "\n"; 
    } */
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue There's an example.

Comment: What exactly is `std::priority_queue<Person>;` supposed to do? That's a type but it's not being used to declare anything.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support `std::priority_queue`. Looking up documentation online I found that `std::priority_queue` is slightly different in the official C++ standards C++98 and C++11. However, I wasn't able to find details on which portions of which standard Visual Studio 2012 supported.

Hopefully someone else on StackOverflow will be able to provide this information.

Barring that, I'd suggest doing a search through the Visual Studio 2012 header files for priority_queue. If it isn't in the header files, then it isn't supported. And you will have to use some other priority queue solution.